# How to create comparator in Java that takes a priority list for comparing?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

In my scenario, I want to compare a list of String, that `B` comes before `A` and `A` comes before `C`, the priority list may be `[B, A, C, D, F ...]`

I am wondering if there is any handy way for creating a comparator with such priority list? I haven't found any online.

Comment: You could use `indexOf` for comparing inside your `Comparator`.

Comment: @QBrute Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy to use external libraries, then Guava's [`Ordering.explicit`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit-T-T...-) generally lets you provide a list of values in the desired order and make a `Comparator` out of that.

Otherwise, if you have a small list of characters in order, you could probably get away with

```
Comparator<Character> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt("BACDF..."::indexOf);
```

If you want to compare *strings* *lexicographically* with this order...it's a little harder and you'll probably have to write it more explicitly.

```
Comparator<String> cmp = (a, b) -> {
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++) {
    if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
      String ordering = "BACDF...";
      return ordering.indexOf(a.charAt(i)) - ordering.indexOf(b.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  return a.length() - b.length();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store the required order in a simple `String`, and then use the index of a char in this `String` to sort some `list`, like this :

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String order = "BACDFE";
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));  //[A, B, C, D, E, F]

    myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(order::indexOf));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));  //[B, A, C, D, F, E]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer from  [@Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475209/982161) is pretty good, but if somehow you need a solution < java8
and without guavas then consider the use of [collators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("car");
myList.add("distro");
myList.add("bar");
myList.add("air");
myList.add("folk");
String simple = "< b< a< c< d";
RuleBasedCollator mySimple = new RuleBasedCollator(simple);
System.out.println(myList);
Collections.sort(myList, mySimple);
System.out.println(myList);
```

the output will look like

before sorting

```
[car, distro, bar, air, folk]
```

after sorting

```
[bar, air, car, distro, folk]
```